# Two wordpress pages with the same permalink

Tags: wordpress

I want to create **two pages** in **wordpress** with the **same permalink**, and without using meta (`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/samepage" />`) 
 what shall I do?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Question doesn't make any sense. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? What's the end goal?

Comment: I want to create in the nav bar menu where I have:
Home|Product|About| Page1|Page2
<br> where "Page1" and "Page2" displays the same page, I mean both of them goes to this links: http://example.com/samepage

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want two pages then, you want two links to the same page. Is that correct? Are you using the Wordpress menu editor?

Comment: yeah I am using wordpress menu editor, so to add a new item to that menu I need to create a new page so I need to create 2 new pages which would have the same permalink I mean will take me to the same page , i hope it is more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if the answer comes too late. But for the benefit of others who read this.

From what I understand you want to two links on your menu to point to the same page/permalink. You can do this doing "Add to Menu" for the same link twice and changing the "Navigation Label" accordingly.

Alternatively, you can create 2 custom links (Page 1 and Page 2) and point to the same URL.